# Help needed with Visualforce Contact Form

Tags: visualforce

I have created a web form with Visualforce pages and a Site page added to our website for visitors to contact us. After they submit, they get an Authorization Required message but their form is submitted correctly.

The user is using a Guest profile for the site.

What can I do to keep the User from getting this message?

Here is my visualforce page code:

```
         <script>
             document.getElementById('{!$Component.ContactForm}').elements['{!$Component.hiddenField}'].value = 'Global Logistics & Supply Chain Mgmt Masters Page';
         </script>

        <apex:inputHidden value="{!contact.Student_Status__c}" id="hiddenStatus"/>

         <script>
             document.getElementById('{!$Component.ContactForm}').elements['{!$Component.hiddenStatus}'].value = 'Inquiry';
         </script>

        <apex:inputHidden value="{!contact.First_Contact__c}" id="hiddenContact"/>

         <script>
             document.getElementById('{!$Component.ContactForm}').elements['{!$Component.hiddenContact}'].value = 'Spring 2017';
         </script>

  </apex:pageBlockSection>
  <!-- Button Section -->
  <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
    <apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!save}" />
  </apex:pageBlockButtons>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post to share your code here...you're likely causing a redirect to an authorized page. Simplest is to not redirect at all and instead rerender page messages (after adding conformation message).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the **[standard controller](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_std.htm)**.  The standard controller **[save() method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_ApexPages_StandardController_methods.htm)** returns a redirect to the newly created record's detail page, which requires authentication. You'll need to write a **[custom controller](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_custom.htm)** or **[controller extension](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_extension.htm)** to resolve this, so you can define your own save behavior (redirect elsewhere, display a message on the current page, etc).

**[Here's a longer tutorial](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/visualforce_fundamentals/units/visualforce_custom_controllers)** to walk you through the creation of a custom controller.